# what is the different between ./* and .:./* in java classpath

Tags: java

In `/home/wangming` dirctory, I wrote a simple java source `Test.java`

```html
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        TimeUnit.HOURS.sleep(1);
    }
}
```

And I put `fastjson-1.2.11.jar` int the directory(the classpath), then I executed

```html
[root@root wangming]# javac -cp ./* Test.java
javac: invalid flag: ./Test.class
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
[root@root wangming]# javac -cp . Test.java
Test.java:2: error: package com.alibaba.fastjson does not exist
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject;
                           ^
Test.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                ^
  symbol:   class JSONObject
  location: class Test
Test.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                                      ^
  symbol:   class JSONObject
  location: class Test
3 errors
[root@root wangming]# javac -cp .:./ Test.java
Test.java:2: error: package com.alibaba.fastjson does not exist
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject;
                           ^
Test.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                ^
  symbol:   class JSONObject
  location: class Test
Test.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                                      ^
  symbol:   class JSONObject
  location: class Test
3 errors
[root@root wangming]# javac -cp .:./* Test.java
```

Only `javac -cp .:./* Test.java` executed successfully, why???

Answer (score 2):

problem is that the Unix/Linux shell expands ./* to anything that matches for instance `./Test.java`

Doing what you do:

```
javac -cp .:./* Test.java
```

disabled the shell match and the shell does not interpret the wildcard anymore => it works.

Which means that that would work as well:

```
javac -cp "./*" Test.java
```

Note: no problem on the windows side, windows shell does not expand wildcards the way Linux/Un*x does.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding `.` which means all the classes under the current directory AND `./*` which means look in all the jar/zip files in the current directory as well.

As Jean-Francois also points out `./*` alone can be expanded to every file in the directory.

I highly recommend using an IDE and a build tool like maven/gradle to setup and build your project and you focus on writing code rather than how you will get it to build/run.

Comment: specially because the IDE has a better chance to avoid recompilation. No problem here, but can take a lot of time on a big project (although it's good to have a simple shell file which does everything from scratch without using IDEs or complex builders)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre for tirival projects a shell script will do the job, but even for projects where I only have one class now, I add a simple maven pom.xml generated by my IDE so I can add things later easily.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to be very simple. You are importing a .jar file.
Thus, you must make the computer search for a **class** and for a **.jar** file to run your app.

When you write to the command-line the following:

```
    javac -cp . Test.java
```

This means "execute javac (compiler), make the classpath the directory where I am in and look for **.java** files (that is what the "." (dot) represents), and if you found Test.java file, compile it".

When one wants to declare more than one classpath, this should be done:

```
-for Windows: path1; path2; path3 (the ";" is the delimiter)

-for Unix systems: path1:path2:path3 (the ":" is the delimiter)
```

Therefore, by writing:

```
    javac -cp .:./* Test.java
```

That means:

```
    -execute javac (compiler), 

    -make the classpath
       1) the directory where I am in and look for .java files 
       2) + look in this directory for .jar files (that is what the "./*" represents,

    -and if you found Test.java file, compile it".
```

This is why your code works. You ask the computer to look inside your current directory for .java files and for all the .jar files in the directory.

Look at this documentation bellow for reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

> **Class Path Wild Cards**
> Class path entries can contain the base name wildcard character (*), which is considered equivalent to specifying a list of all of the files in the directory with the extension .jar or .JAR. For example, the class path entry mydir/* specifies all JAR files in the directory named mydir. A class path entry consisting of * expands to a list of all the jar files in the current directory. Files are considered regardless of whether they are hidden (have names beginning with '.').

> A class path entry that contains an asterisk (*) does not match class files. To match both classes and JAR files in a single directory mydir, use either mydir:mydir/* or mydir/*:mydir. The order chosen determines whether the classes and resources in mydir are loaded before JAR files in mydir or vice versa.

> Subdirectories are not searched recursively. For example, mydir/* searches for JAR files only in mydir, not in mydir/subdir1, mydir/subdir2, and so on.

> The order in which the JAR files in a directory are enumerated in the expanded class path is not specified and may vary from platform to platform and even from moment to moment on the same machine. A well-constructed application should not depend upon any particular order. If a specific order is required, then the JAR files can be enumerated explicitly in the class path.

> Expansion of wild cards is done early, before the invocation of a program's main method, rather than late, during the class-loading process. Each element of the input class path that contains a wildcard is replaced by the (possibly empty) sequence of elements generated by enumerating the JAR files in the named directory. For example, if the directory mydir contains a.jar, b.jar, and c.jar, then the class path mydir/* is expanded into mydir/a.jar:mydir/b.jar:mydir/c.jar, and that string would be the value of the system property java.class.path.

> The CLASSPATH environment variable is not treated any differently from the -classpath or -cp options. Wild cards are honored in all of these cases. However, class path wild cards are not honored in the Class-Path jar-manifest header.